# Can I add a field from a different Model to a View in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a View that is associated to model: ICS_Orders.  this view is used for the users to print a form with records.

The users have requested a new field be present on the print view.  This field is not part of the ICS_Orders model, but rather ICS_Supplies.   I can't seem to find any information as to how I can get this field to display on the view - from a different model.

View Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Orders>

<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>PO / Requisition Number</th>
<th>Units Ordered</th>
<th>Supply Name</th>
<th>**New Field from Different Model Here**  </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequisitionNumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsOrdered)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supply)</td>
    <td>**New Field Display Resuls** <td>
    </tr>
         }
     </table>
```

As you can see the view is for

```
@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Orders>
```

The new requested field (Old_ItemID) is for:

```
@model IEnumerable<ICS20web.Models.ICS_Supplies>
```

(WHERE item.Supply (from current model: ICS_Orders) = item.Description (in new model: ICS_Supplies))

Is there a way to do this?  Or do I have to go all the way back and create a view in my database and a new model ?

EDIT:

Below is my ICS_Orders Model

```
public class ICS_Orders
{      
    [Key]
    public int? LineID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RequisitionNumber { get; set; }

    public int SuppliesID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UnitsOrdered { get; set; }

    public string Supply { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> UnitsDelivered { get; set; }

}
```

How do I add a property to hold the ICS_Supplies field 'Old_ITemID' ?  I tried the following, and it did not work.

```
public virtual DbSet<ICS_Supplies> ICS_Order { get; set; }

public string Old_ItemID { get; set; }
```

And what do I need to do in my controller to "set this"  as was suggested.

Comment: Why not add a property to `ICS_Orders` to hold the id of ICS_Supplies, then set this in your controller?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - thank you for your reply.  I am relatively new to MVC.  I took a shot at doing what you recommended and it was an epic fail.  Any chance you can provide a quick example of how to add the property to an existing model and then how to set it in controller?  Or point to some information online that I can read?

Comment: @ExecChief can you post your current controller code and I will provide an answer? It's difficult to give something concrete without seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1. Create a new list OrdersWithSupplies in the controller and use that as your model. You would fill the OrderWithSupply class with the Order and Supply data.
2. Create a new view model which contains both a list of Orders and a list of Supplies. If they are equal in length you can loop through one of them and use the current index to retrieve the correct supply data.

To illustrate:

```
@for(var i=0;i<Model.Orders.Length;i++)
        {
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Orders[i].SomeOrderProp)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Supplies[i].SomeSupplyProp)</td>
```

If you clearly show your models and controller, I'll be able to narrow down this answer even more :)

Answer (score 0):

in action store your New Field Display Results in `ViewBag.Results` as below

```
ViewBag.Results = New Field Display Resulst.Tolist();
```

Also in razor

```
<ul>
@foreach (var Result in ViewBag.Results )
{
    <li>@Result</li>
}
</ul>
```